# Leaflet not updating the distance value when markers are changing position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I have an `angularjs` application which uses leaflet maps.
This applications intends to measure the distance (in meters) between 2 markers.
When loading the distance is measured correctly but when moving the markers the distance is NOT updated as expected. Seems to be that when a marker is dragged the method specified by `ng-change` is not called.

I do not see why this happen.

The following code is a simplified version of the code:

```
Number.prototype.toRad = function() {return this * Math.PI / 180;}

function distance(lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2) {
    var R = 6371000; // meter
    var Phi1 = lat1.toRad();
var Phi2 = lat2.toRad();
var DeltaPhi = (lat2 - lat1).toRad();
var DeltaLambda = (lon2 - lon1).toRad();

var a = Math.sin(DeltaPhi / 2) * Math.sin(DeltaPhi / 2)
        + Math.cos(Phi1) * Math.cos(Phi2) * Math.sin(DeltaLambda / 2)
        * Math.sin(DeltaLambda / 2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
var d = R * c;

return d;
}

var munichMarkers = {
    munich1 : {
        lat : 48.14959568930188,
        lng : 11.528091430664062,
        draggable : true},

    munich2 : {
        lat : 48.123246933031844,
        lng : 11.6070556640625,
        draggable : true}
};  

var demoapp = angular.module("demoapp", ["leaflet-directive" ]);

    demoapp.controller("DemoController", [ "$scope", "$http", "$location", "leafletData", 
             function ($scope, $http, $location, leafletData) {             

angular.extend($scope, {
  markers: {},            
  europeanPaths: {},     
  cen: {
    lat: 48.1333,
    lng: 11.5667,
    zoom: 12
  }           
}); 

angular.extend($scope, {
  markers: munichMarkers
});

angular.extend($scope, {
europeanPaths: {
    muenchenArea: {
    latlngs: [ $scope.markers.munich1, $scope.markers.munich2],
    type: 'rectangle',
    color: '#FF0000',
    weight: 3,
    stroke: true
    }
  }
});

$scope.dist = distance($scope.markers.munich1.lat, $scope.markers.munich2.lat,             $scope.markers.munich1.lng, $scope.markers.munich2.lng); 

$scope.change = function() {            
        $scope.dist = distance($scope.markers.munich1.lat, $scope.markers.munich2.lat,     $scope.markers.munich1.lng, $scope.markers.munich2.lng); 
        alert("called");                
 }; 
 }]);
</script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="DemoController">  
    <form>      
    Distance  : <input ng-model="dist" ng-change="change()" />      
    </form>
    <leaflet center="cen" width="640" height="400" paths="europeanPaths" markers="markers"></leaflet>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) they say:

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model. It will not be evaluated: 
>   * if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline has not changed 
>   * if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null 
>   * if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

So if it were me I would try to verify if change() is firing off (by logging it or something).  If it's not firing off then I would see if that third bullet is the case.

Comment: As you can see the function change() has an alert which is NOT being called. The point is exactly why change() is not called.